# Find How many times an Anagram is contained in a String - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to find how many times the Anagrams are contained in a String like in this example:(the anagrams and the string itself)

Input 1(String) = thegodsanddogsweredogged

Input 2(String) = dog

Output(int) = 3 
the output will be 3 because of these - (the**god**sand**dog**swere**dog**ged)

So far i managed to check how many times the word "dog" is contained in the string:

```
        public ActionResult FindAnagram (string word1, string word2)
        {
            int ?count = Regex.Matches(word1, word2).Count;

            return View(count);
        }
```

This works to check how many times the word is contained but i still get an error: Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nulable value type.

So i need to check for how many times `input 2` and the anagrams of `input 2`(dog,god,dgo,ogd etc) are contained in `input 1`?(int this case its 3 times-the**god**sand**dog**swere**dog**ged)

Thank you

Comment: Do you allow for overlap? Does "dogdo" contain 3 anagrams of dog (dog, ogd, gdo)?

Comment: no overlaps, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to post a variation which is more readable at the cost of some runtime performance. Anton's answer is probably more performant, but IMHO less readable than it could be.

The nice thing about anagrams is that you know their exact length, and you can figure out all possible anagram locations quite easily. For a 3 letter anagram in a 100 letter haystack, you know that there are 98 possible locations:

- 0..2
- 1..3
- 2..4
- ...
- 96..98
- 97..99

These indexes can be generated quite easily:

```
var amountOfPossibleAnagramLocations = haystack.Length - needle.Length + 1;

var substringIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, amountOfPossibleAnagramLocations);
```

At this point, you simply take every listed substring and test if it's an anagram.

```
var anagramLength = needle.Length;
int count = 0;

foreach(var index in substringIndexes)
{
    var substring = haystack.Substring(index, anagramLength);

    if(substring.IsAnagramOf(needle))
        count++;
}
```

Note that a lot of this can be condensed into a single LINQ chain:

```
var amountOfPossibleAnagramLocations = haystack.Length - needle.Length + 1;
var anagramLength = needle.Length;

var anagramCount = Enumerable
                      .Range(0, amountOfPossibleAnagramLocations)
                      .Select(x => haystack.Substring(x, anagramLength))
                      .Count(substring => substring.IsAnagramOf(needle));
```

Whether it's more readable or not depends on how comfortable you are with LINQ. I personally prefer it (up to a reasonable size, of course).

---

To check for an anagram, simply sort the characters and check for equality. I used an extension method for the readability bonus:

```
public static bool IsAnagramOf(this string word1, string word2)
{
    var word1Sorted = String.Concat(word1.OrderBy(c => c));
    var word2Sorted = String.Concat(word2.OrderBy(c => c));

    return word1Sorted == word2Sorted;
}
```

I've omitted things like case insensitivity or ignoring whitespace for the sake of brevity.

Comment: thank you, i will try to implement both answers and i will respond

Comment: Should i make a method (IsAnagramOf) in the controller, more speciffic in the ActionResult? Or i should just use the code? What is better? Besides that i understand much better your example, for me as a beginner it seems much more easier. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: in the end i have put the method ```IsAnagramOf``` outside of the ```ActionResult``` and modified the ```if ``` to                 ```if(IsAnagramOf(substring, neddle))
                    count++; ``` This way seems to work.

Comment: @sgcata: If you make it a string extension method, it tends to go in a toolkit/helpers section, which is often in a folder/project of its own. But you could just as well have this method as part of your "anagram checker service" class (though not as an extension method then). There is no universal rule of where it should go, categorize it as appropriate according to your codebase. None of your business logic belongs in the controller though, as the controller has its own purpose (routing web requests _to_ your business logic)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better not to try to use Regex but write your own logic.

You can use a dictionary with key `char` - a letter of the word and value `int` - number of letter occurrences. And build such a dictionary for the word.

Anagrams will have similar dictionaries, so you can build a temp dictionary for each temp string built using the Windowing method over your str and compare it with the dictionary built for your word.

Here is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var str = "thegodsanddogsweredogged";
            var word = "dog";
            Console.WriteLine("Word: " + word);
            Console.WriteLine("Str: " + str);
            Console.WriteLine();

            var count = CountAnagrams(str, word);
            Console.WriteLine("Count: " + count);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        private static int CountAnagrams(string str, string word) {
            var charDict = BuildCharDict(word);
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length - word.Length + 1; i++) {
                string tmp = "";
                for (int j = i; j < str.Length; j++) {
                    tmp += str[j];
                    if (tmp.Length == word.Length)
                        break;
                }

                var tmpCharDict = BuildCharDict(tmp);

                if (CharDictsEqual(charDict, tmpCharDict)) {
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Anagram: " + tmp);
                    Console.WriteLine("Index: " + i);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }


            return count;
        }

        private static Dictionary<char, int> BuildCharDict(string word) {
            var charDict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            foreach (var ch in word)
            {
                if (charDict.ContainsKey(ch))
                {
                    charDict[ch] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    charDict[ch] = 1;
                }
            }

            return charDict;
        }

        private static bool CharDictsEqual(Dictionary<char, int> dict1, Dictionary<char, int> dict2) 
        {
            if (dict1.Count != dict2.Count)
                return false;

            foreach (var kv in dict1) {
                if (!dict2.TryGetValue(kv.Key, out var val) || val != kv.Value)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        } 
    }
}
```

Possibly there is a better solution, but mine works.

P.S. About your error. You should change `int?` to `int`, because your View might expect non-nullable `int` type

Comment: Not trying to foist my own solution into this, I'm genuinely curious: is there a known performance gain from generating the dictionary comparing to sorting the string characters and doing a simple equality check?

Comment: @Flater It would be cool to create a benchmark for our solutions because it is interesting for me too. Possible, I'll do it when I am free. It looks like your code has a lot of allocations for string objects

Comment: I think mine can be optimized to just fetch the characters from the array instead of making new strings, but I was trying to maximize readability (and staying away from index juggling as much as possible) rather than trying to find a middle ground :)